# d3 convert objects to arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

Struggling with this, and have red all the similar questions.

I am using d3 library to read in a csv on a webpage.

I currently have this:

```
  d3.csv("normal.csv", function(rows) {
     doSomethingWithRows(rows);
  });

  function doSomethingWithRows(rows) {
    // do something with rows
    console.log(rows);  
 }
```

This outputs me this:

-an array for all the rows

-each index as object (each row is an object)

so its an array with objects.

What I would like is an array of arrays, so i could reference things like an 2D array.

I looked at jquery-csv but that didnt help in converting to array of array. Also looked at d3.csv.parser but it didnt help either.

Any ideas

Comment: `$.csv.toArrays(csv)` in the [jquery-csv docs](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: but the things is "csv" needs be a string. Only d3 (which i could find) can load csv file when you load a webpage.

Comment: why can't you convert the array of objects into an array of arrays yourself? is there some restriction which prevents you from doing that?

Comment: i am unsure on how to convert the array of objects to array. 
I am trying to make it a 2D array

Comment: you can load it via [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and then transform it.

Comment: its a local file and hence ajax wont work in this case

Comment: Coming from python pandas/numpy, the fact that d3 tries to parse my 2D data arrays as arrays of hashmaps is REALLY bizarre.  It would be nice if there were some handy function to just load my csv naively without trying to anticipate my future needs.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to understand what you are trying to do.

1. Each object should correspond to an array within the outer array, which does not change length. In which case, you want **map** or an **accessor function** (see docs for d3.csv).
2. You want to keep the same number of elements but arrange them with two indices instead of one. In this case, I recommend you keep your data as one-dimensional and do math on the index later. D3 makes the array index available to you whenever you'd need it.
3. You want to create a 2D array where each element draws from multiple objects in the array you have. The exact transformation depends on what you're trying to do, but I would look at the [D3 docs for Arrays](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays), which helpfully list some plain JavaScript methods at the top. In particular, look at `pairs` and `zip`. You can also look at the `nest` data structure. If you want a grid or matrix, see [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663) and in particular the function `cross`.
4. (In response to comment) You want to use the 2D structure of the CSV itself. You basically already have this, except that the inner data structure is key-value rather than by index. This takes advantage of CSV headers and the fact that CSV columns is frequently heterogenous and do not admit numerical ordering. If you really want to change the values into an array, use map or an accessor function. By I can't really see why you'd want to, besides [d3.transpose](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_transpose).

That being said, D3 code (or at least the simplest D3 code) is oriented around one-dimensional data. You should think hard about whether you really need a 2D array. It's hard to jump right in to D3 and make your own charts; you'd do well to read some [tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) and get a sense for how it works and the opinions it has.

Comment: would you know any other libraries in which i can parse csv data to a 2D array? I am not interested in charts,  but d3 was the only library that could load csv when webpage was loaded.